# How can I capture and stream video from the iPhone's camera?

Tags: iphone, video

What's the best, most convenient, and most Apple-permitted way of streaming video from the iPhone's camera to a server on the Internet (or local network)?

uStream, Qik, Justin.tv, etc.. Are all able to do it, but I'm finding very little love from my searches. It seems that the traditional way of doing it was to use UIGetScreenImage(), but surely there is a more "modern" since video recording is now part of the API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [AV Foundation Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/00_Introduction.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH1-SW3).